# How can I understand Wordpress custom functions?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I am using a custom theme and there is a line that says `<?php sg_header_js() ?>`. My assumption was to view Wordpress's functions folder in order to get a better idea. When I look inside functions>function.php this is the code I see:

```
<?php

//Textdomain
define('SG_TDN', 'felis');

//Add features or post thumbnail sizes here
function sg_user_theme_setup()
{
    /* Add theme-supported features. */
    /* add_theme_support(''); */

    /* Add images sizes */
    /* Please use 'cm_' prefix to name */
    /* add_image_size('cm_myimage', 100, 100, true); */
}

//Theme Setup
require_once TEMPLATEPATH . '/functions/init.php';
```

Where should I look to find the javascript files?

Comment: You can look them up by opening the Wordpress folder in My Computer and pressing F3. JS files match the pattern `*.js` and they're pretty much everywhere in Wordpress.

Comment: sg_header_js just do a find search throughout the directory and it will turn it up.

Answer (score 1):

The ways you can find this information:

- They might be hardcoded to `header.php` of your theme.
- Usually they are included in `js, scripts, lib` like folders
- look at the functions that hook to "`wp_head`" method.
- look at the compiled source from the browser to see which js files are included in  tags or some scripts may be included in body. Search the source for `.js?` or `.js"` strings.
- if the theme is using script compression, then you'll see one script file named like "compressed.js" or something. look for the functions or plugins that creates it, it may tell you something.